Finite differences stability issue for PDE
Lets say I have the following centered space (x, first index) forward time (t, second index) scheme for a coupled system of partial DEs:
$$u[j, k+1] = u[j, k] - \frac{\Delta t} {2 \cdot  \Delta x} \cdot \left( v[j+1, k] - v[j-1, k]\right)$$
$$v[j, k+1] = v[j, k]- \gamma \frac{\Delta t} {2 \cdot  \Delta x} \cdot (u[j+1, k+1] - u[j-1, k+1])$$
I observe instability when $\Delta t$ is too small. But how can this be quantified? For ODEs in one variable I would calculate the harmonic Eigenvalues to answer stability issues, but here we have $x$ and $t$ and two coupled quantities $u(x,t)$ and $v(x,t)$. What is the recipe to apply here?

First examine if the PDE system has some "energy" that should be conserved or bounded. Does your numerical method satisfy similar property ? You can do FOURIER stability analysis, you will obtain an amplification matrix and you need to look at its eigenvalues.
